# Comparison of various improvements to Hagan's SABR formula?

Tags: sabr-model, finite-difference

There has been several papers improving the original Hagan's approximation formula (see this [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/26268/26559)) to SABR model. At least, I know three below:

- [Obloj](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.0998)
- [Paulot](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0658) (Also see this [thread](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/37143/26559))
- [Balland](https://www.risk.net/derivatives/interest-rate-derivatives/2269613/sabr-goes-normal) ([Download](http://janroman.dhis.org/finance/OIS/Artiklar%20%C3%B6vrigt/SABR%20goes%20Normal.pdf))

Is there any research comparing the accuracy of them? I assume that the error can be measured from the option value solved with finite difference method?

Also, is there finite difference implementation openly available?